# Percentage difference between different values in the same keys of two different arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for a solution to this problem.
I got 2 arrays, like this:

```
    array(2) { 
       [20100526]=>  array(1) { 
           ["ga:pageviews"]=>  string(5) "19088" 
       } 
       [20100527]=>  array(1) {
           ["ga:pageviews"]=>  string(5) "15566" 
       } 
    } 

 array(2) { 
        [20100526]=>  array(1) { 
            ["ga:pageviews"]=>  string(5) "12043" 
        } 
        [20100527]=>  array(1) {
            ["ga:pageviews"]=>  string(5) "11953" 
        } 
    }
```

Now I'd like to create a new array, with the **% difference** between the values per key.

Would be something like this:

```
array(2) { 
            [20100526]=>  array(1) { 
                ["ga:pageviews"]=>  string(5) "88,23" 
            } 
            [20100527]=>  array(1) {
                ["ga:pageviews"]=>  string(5) "74,54" 
            } 
        }
```

Can anyone help me how to create that array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array_map(function($a,$b){
    $a['ga:pageviews'] = ($b['ga:pageviews']/$a['ga:pageviews'])*100;
    return $a;),
 $array1,$array2);
```